# Update Parent child Detail in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have Panel header and Panel body when I click Panel header I want to update that panel body with their respective data.You can check the plunker when I click
"Test1" Panel header I want to update only "Test1detail" only to that body using angular.

[click for the plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/qZ7Z9VRxndpVsHiEca8S?p=preview)

Below is my code in plunkr

```
angular.module('myapp',[])
.controller('maincontroller',function($scope,myservice){
  var headings=['Test1','Test2','Test3']
  $scope.mainHeadings=headings

  $scope.GetDetail= function(header)
  {
$scope.headerdetail = myservice.GetDetails(header);

  }

})



angular.module('myapp')
.service('myservice',function()
{
var test1='test1 detail'; 
var test2='test2 detail';
var test3='test3 detail';

var Details = function(det)
{

  if (det=='Test1')
  return test1
  else if (det=='Test2')
  return test2
  if (det=='Test3')
  return test3
}

  return {
  GetDetails: Details
  }

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**#1**. You set `$scope.headerdetail` property which is shared by all panels. Instead you cat set current iteration scope `headerdetail` variable:

```
$scope.GetDetail = function(header) {
    this.headerdetail = myservice.GetDetails(header);
}
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/pzx1G2PjZrdazH8E5OnQ?p=preview

**#2**. But much better if you dealed with array of objects as your primary data structure:

```
var headings = [{title: 'Test1'}, {title: 'Test2'}, {title: 'Test3'}];

$scope.mainHeadings = headings;

$scope.GetDetail = function(heading) {
    heading.headerdetail = myservice.GetDetails(heading.title);
}
```

and then you would set a property of the `heading` object:

```
<div class='panel panel-default' ng-repeat='heading in mainHeadings'>
    <div class='panel-heading pnlbld active' data-loaded='false' ng-click='GetDetail(heading)'>{{heading.title}}</div>
    <div class='panel-body'>
        {{heading.headerdetail}}
    </div>
</div>
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/zxB6LUoEarqmNJYy0ihk?p=info